# Page braek after group header in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008

1. Hi I I would like to  put page break after group header, how can i
   do this using SSRS.  Thanks in advance. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In the Grouping pane, right-click a row group, and then click Group Properties.

On the Page Breaks tab, select Between each instance of a group to add a page break between each instance of a group in the table.

Optionally, select Also at the start of a group or Also at the end of a group to specify that a page break be added when a group starts or ends in the table.